# Angular 15 - "Unkown error" on HttpRequest to server I developed

Tags: angular, httprequest, angular-httpclient

I am developing a website with Angular 15 and I get the data from two APIs. One is public (The Movie Database) and I had no problem working with it.

I developed the other one and is deployed on my school server. I know my API works well because I tested it on several environments. I only have this problem on the website. I need to hide the url for privacy issues.

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class LoginService {

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}

  public login(userName: string, password: string): Observable<UserRemote> {
    return this.httpClient
      .get<UserRemote>(
        'http://[...]/api/users/login?username=' + userName + '&password=' + password
      )
      .pipe(
        map((response) => {
          return response;
        }),
        catchError((error) => {
          console.log('Error: ' + error.message);
          return throwError(() => error.message);
        }),
      );
  }
}
```

All I get when running it is "Unkown error":
[image: Error image]

The only difference I can tell from this url and one from The Movie Database is that it is http:// instead of https://. While working on an Android app, I had the same issue and I could fix it by adding allowcleartext=true, but I can't find the equivalent for Angular.

I tried using:
**this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('http://[...]/api/users/login?username=' + userName + '&password=' + password);**.
I'm not sure how it works, so it probably doesn't make sense here.

Comment: Yes! That was the problem, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like something CORS-related because the error doesn't say much (and doesn't look like it's being thrown directly from your API either)

You might want to check your `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header / configuration